# Get me out of the Angulars css-hell! (seeks a css-fix strategy)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Since my first program in 1980, I feel that I am more of a user than a programmer. That is a good thing. Angular is a great example. I don't need to know its inner workings to create acceptable code. Unless a textarea is rendered a bit too narrow, as I am fighting right now.

Angular documents it as follows: [Avoid defining custom styles that would affect the size or internal layout of the component](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) I could read it ten times but it is too complicated for a programming user of Angular Material.

Then I google and find solutions here that may have worked in other versions, but not for me today.

What I need is a **strategy** to get my CSS working. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: share the problem you are facing along with code, if possible a working example on stackblitz and screenshots on what you want to achieve

Comment: @Narren Murali. The code is very simple ...``            <textarea #textArea
                      matInput
                      style="width: 40vw;"
                      [(ngModel)]="data.text"
                      (keyup.enter)="sendTweet(data)"
                      (keyup)="showAuto($event)"
                      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            ></textarea>
`` See the style element. It is not working. Btw, thanks for the -1. That is very kind of you.

Comment: make a difference between Angular and Angular Material.
In Angular using CSS should be almost the same as normal HTML.

Angular Material is a UI component Library. Customizing the style can be tricky and should be avoided when possible. If you want to use Material then you should not change the style ;)

Comment: @otembajelle that was not me, but please give detailed questions like mentioned

Comment: @NarenMurali sorry, about that. Please ignore.

Comment: When posting my cry, my css trials with flexbox did not become active. I finally found out that I missed the import instructions of https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout. Now that I did, my css works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to override the Angular Material UI, one of the simplest way is to define the css in the main `styles.scss` (not the one in the component) i.e:

```
mat-form-field {

  &.my-class {
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

```
<mat-form-field class="my-class">
  <mat-label>My Textarea</mat-label>
  <textarea matInput></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

sometimes you need to have a more specific rule or us `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Zerotwelves solution that worked for me. Component:

```
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="3">
        <mat-form-field class="myTextArea" [formControl]="control">
            <textarea
                      #textArea
                      matInput
                      [(ngModel)]="data.text"
                      (keyup.enter)="sendTweet(data)"
                      (keyup)="showAuto($event)"
                      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            ></textarea>
```

Removed: `style="width: 40vw;"` from the components css and its html.

Added to the global styles.css:

```
.myTextArea {
    width: 40vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the component that you are trying to change styles of. For example, for simple properties of mat-form-field you can simple add the CSS in the same component or use a bootstrap class directly on it.

account.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100 or-your-class">
  <mat-label>
    <i class="fcp fcp-envelope mr-1"></i>Account Email
  </mat-label>
  <input type="email" matInput class="text-dark" formControlName="accountEmail" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

account.component.css

```
.or-your-class{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

But there are HTML Elements that are created beyond that components "scope", to apply the styles to those HTML Elements either you can turn off ViewEncapsulation *(not recommended)* or You can add the styles in your top most .css file which is usually the styles.css as well as using `!important` to override the styles of that Material UI Component